# Checking equality of interface{}

Tags: go, types, interface, equality

I am searching a `[]interface{}` slice for a given `interface{}` value:

```
var v interface{}
for i := 0; i < len(A); i++ {
  if (A[i] == v) {
    fmt.Println("Gotcha!")
    break
  }
}
```

In the trivial case the types are `int`. However what should I do if, for example, the types are some custom `struct`?

Comment: If the structs are [comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators), then the code works as is.

Comment: to expand on that a bit, quoting from @CodingPickle's linked doc: `Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.`

Comment: related: [Is it possible to compare two interface values in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944464)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Thanks to @CodingPickle comment, I provide the following from the [Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

> The equality operators == and != apply to operands that are comparable.

Regarding `interface{}`s and `structs`:

- Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.
- A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T are comparable when values of type X are comparable and X implements T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's dynamic value is equal to x.
- Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

You can also try this playground https://play.golang.org/p/bgO1_V87v9k

In other words, handling equality seems easy in Go!

Answer (score 8):

I have a summary of properties of Go types

[image: properties of Go types]

Explanation

- `depends` - it's only allowed if the contained type(s) are comparable.) For **Interface** types the code will compile but if at runtime the types contained are not comparable then the runtime will panic. Thanks to @Andrew W. Phillips.

Comment: The table is a good idea but it is slightly wrong for Interface type. (You should also explain what is meant by `depends` - it's only allowed if the contained type(s) are comparable.)

For Interface types the code will compile but if at runtime the types contained are not comparable then the runtime will *panic*.

Answer (score 6):

I am correcting my previous answer as I now believe it was wrong. When two interface values are compared the run-time will only panic if they are of the same type and it is *non-comparable*. If they contain different types then the result is false even if one or both types are non-comparable.

What are non-comparable types?  Basically, they are slices, maps, functions and any struct or array type that uses them.

Answer (score 5):

```
reflect.DeepEqual(x, y any) bool
```

worked.