# How are two interfaces matched in golang

Tags: go, interface

How are interface{} values compared if I have a type of `map[interface{}]interface{}` and I have another map which has map[string]interface{}.

How are the hashes evaluated if I have a 
`m := make(map[string]interface{})` and I execute `m[m["key"]]` i.e. I am passing an interface{} value for a map with string as key.

And vice versa case, that is : 
`m1 := make(map[interface{}]interface{})` and I execute `m1[m["key"]]`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the maps have to do with comparing interfaces. Are you asking how those maps are compared to each other, how the interfaces are hashed in the map compared to a string, or how 2 interfaces are compared directly?

Comment: @JimB I have updated the question. I am asking about how hashes are evaluated in the two scenarios.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang - Checking equality of interface{}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245932/golang-checking-equality-of-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go interfaces are a 2 word value, and are compared as such. From the [Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) section on [Comparison Operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

- Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.
- A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T are comparable when values of type X are comparable and X implements T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's dynamic value is equal to x.

Only the first point is relevant in the case of the `map[interface{}]T`, since the key is always converted to an `interface{}` for comparison.

Comment: I updated the 1st scenario of question. What would happen in that case.

Comment: @Prateek: that's invalid, because an `interface{}` is not assignable to a `string`.

Comment: Yeah... Without type assertion it will give a compile error.