# Go auto type conversion - comparing inteface{} to concrete type

Tags: go

If I want to compare two types - **string** and **interface{}** I usually write:

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    var p1 interface{}
    var p2 string

    p1 = "123"
    p2 = "123"

    if v, ok := p1.(string); ok {
        log.Println(v == p2)
    } else {
        log.Println("false")    
    }
}
```

I think it is save variant when **type(p1) != string**.
But is it correct if I write?:

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    var p1 interface{}
    var p2 string

    p1 = "123"
    p2 = "123"

    log.Println(p1 == p2)
}
```

If type(p1) != string there was not a error. But it is the same variant or I should write previous one?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245932/checking-equality-of-interface answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your immediate question is **yes**, though the original code (first snippet in your question) shows more thoughtfulness about type checking so it could be more correct from a SW engineering point of view. It's hard to tell without understanding more context.

---

According to the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if
>   they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both
>   have value nil.
>
> A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T
>   are comparable when values of type X are comparable and X implements
>   T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's
>   dynamic value is equal to x.

I believe what you're asking falls under the terms of the second paragraph here.