# invalid operation: a > b (operator > not defined on interface)

Tags: go, interface

Is it possible to compare two interface values in Go?

For example:

```golang
func compare(a interface{}, b interface{}) {
    if a > b {
        fmt.Printf("%v is bigger than %v", a, b)
    }
}
```

But finally, I got the compiler error:

```sh
invalid operation: a > b (operator > not defined on interface)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/iyfw3u6-VeY

Answer (score 6):

You can compare interface values for equality, but not for order.

The Go specs may sound a little confusing because the relevant paragraph is called [**Comparison** operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) but then proceeds to distinguish between equality comparison and order comparison (emphasis mine):

> The equality operators `==` and `!=` apply to operands that are **comparable**. The ordering operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` apply to operands that are **ordered**. These terms and the result of the comparisons are defined as follows:

And then:

> - Integer values are comparable and ordered, in the usual way.
> - [...]
> - Interface values are **comparable**. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.

The point about interfaces does not mention order, therefore you can infer that interface values are **not ordered**. Hence, your example using the operator `>` doesn't compile.

This, using equality operators, instead works:

```
type A struct {
    val int8
}

func main() {
    var x, y int = 1, 2

    compare(x, y) // a and b are not equal

    compare(nil, nil) // a and b are equal

    compare(A{12}, A{12}) // a and b are equal

    compare(A{12}, A{45}) // a and b are not equal
}

func compare(a interface{}, b interface{}) {
    if a == b {
        fmt.Println("a and b are equal")
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("a and b are not equal")
}
```

As an additional note, consider that code that compiles may still panic when the interface values are not equality-comparable. Quoting the [Go specs again](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> A comparison of two interface values with identical dynamic types causes a **run-time panic if values of that type are not comparable**. This behavior applies not only to direct interface value comparisons but also when comparing arrays of interface values or structs with interface-valued fields.
>
> Slice, map, and function values are **not comparable**.

This means that the following code compiles but panics at runtime:

```
compare([]int{12}, []int{12}) // panic: runtime error: comparing uncomparable type []int
```

**Caveat**: the paragraph above specifies "*identical dynamic types*", so if you compare two interfaces with different types, even if one or both are not comparable, the comparison will **not panic and return false**:

```
    var a interface{} = 500             // numerical: comparable
    var b interface{} = []string{"foo"} // slice: not comparable
    fmt.Println(a == b)                 // false
```

See the code in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zRgW1ilbpDL)

---

As an alternative, with Go 1.18 and generics, you can explicitly constrain the types of the arguments to orderable types, and then you'll be able to use order operators in the function body:

```
func compare[T constraints.Ordered](a, b T) {
    // works
    if a > b {
        fmt.Printf("%v is bigger than %v", a, b)
    }
}
```