# Why can't I compare net.Addr?

Tags: go

I am trying to understand/learn why I can't compare two identical net.Addr.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245932/checking-equality-of-interface), it seems that two interfaces should be able to be compared if they are of the same underlying type and that type can be compared.  In my example below, the underlying type is [net.UDPAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/net#UDPAddr). It is a struct containing a string, int and a [net.IP](https://pkg.go.dev/net#IP), which is a type alias of []byte.

Is it because the slice IP is not comparable?  Even though its type, length and contents are identical?

Example:

https://go.dev/play/p/dIzRCTwBA4P

Comment: The standard library provides a [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#DeepEqual) function which is more forgiving than `==`. You can try it, but read the docs carefully to see if the behaviour matches what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example compares the values returned from two calls to [`net.ResolveUDPAddr`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#ResolveUDPAddr). However if you consider the function signature:

> func ResolveUDPAddr(network, address string) (*UDPAddr, error)

You will note that you are actually comparing two pointers; these are comparable but will not be equal  (you are comparing the pointer; not the value it points to).

As per the [go spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Struct types are comparable if all their field types are comparable.
> Slice, map, and function types are not comparable. However, as a special case, a slice, map, or function value may be compared to the predeclared identifier nil.

[net.UDPAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/net#UDPAddr) contains a [`net.IP`](https://pkg.go.dev/net#IP) which is a `[]byte` and, therefore, not comparable.

[This](https://go.dev/play/p/HLLxiUUhrwS) extension of your example may help.

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right.  I have corrected my example.  It now fails on the comparison as expected.  I knocked that example up super quickly for the post and didn't test it (blush).

Comment: No worries, I assumed as much, so hopefully the second half of my answer provides the info you want (i.e. "Slice, map, and function types are not comparable").

Comment: I dont understand go under the hood but it does seem to me that it would be nice if a slice could be compared it should be able to be compared...

Comment: That is a question for the language designers! You will find some reasons [in the faq](https://go.dev/doc/faq#map_keys) (I realise the question is about maps but most of the answer is about slice equality).

Comment: You may also find [this proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/23725) (and the [linked discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/ajXzEM6lqJI)) of interest.

Comment: The rules in that proposal are similar to those followed by refelctions DeepCopy.  Makes complete sense to me.  I hope one day they implement it.  for now I vahe caompared using the String() method on each item, but does feel wasteful.

Comment: See [`slices.Equal`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Equal).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `[]bytes` representation of IP address (`a1.IP`) to `string` and then compare them directly with `==` or use `slices.Equal` as suggested by @jub0bs.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "slices"
)

func main() {
    a1, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "192.168.0.1:1234")
    a2, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "192.168.0.1:1234")
    // we are casting []bytes to string
    ip1 := string(a1.IP.To4())
    ip2 := string(a2.IP.To4())
    // we are using slices package
    fmt.Println(slices.Equal(a1.IP, a2.IP))
    fmt.Println(ip1 == ip2)
}

Output:
true
true
```

Source Code: [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ZTKFvdfMacQ)